# Why does secondary screen turns black when selecting "Mirror Display"

Tags: display

I have a MacBook Retina.

Whenever I attach a secondary screen, projector or monitor and select the "Mirror Displays" option, the secondary screen turns all black.

It does not matter what connection I use. I've tried the following, and they all have problems:

- MiniDisplay port to a Cinema Display
- HDMI to HDTV
- MiniDisplay -> VGA/DVI converter -> projector

It does not matter what resolution I use.

It all started after connecting it to a projector, where all other presenters using PC was having similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by [resetting NVRAM / PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379):

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
3. Turn on the computer.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen
   appears.
5. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
6. Release the keys.